# safeAreaLayoutGuide returning wrong values on blocked rotation

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios11, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

In my application I do have two viewControllers:

`VideoListViewController` - portrait only

`VideoPlayerViewController` - landscape only

`VideoListViewController` opens `VideoPlayerViewController` via `self.present(viewController...)`

I'm blocking orientations via:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask 
{
    return .portrait
}
```

My problem is that portrait only view receives the landspace safe area...
On my `VideoListViewController.layoutSubviews` I printed `self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame` and it works as expected at first returning `{{0, 44}, {375, 734}}` (portrait mode), but then when the VideoPlayer appears in landspace rotation my portrait-only viewController gets `{{44, 0}, {287, 791}}`

Effect is that for a slight moment old view updates ignoring safe area and it fixes itself when `ViewPlayerViewController` disappears.

Did anyone had this problem ? Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: I went for UIViewContainment instead of presenting ViewController to avoid that effect. I couldn't find a better way of working around this problem.

Comment: I've got a similar issue when an iPhone with notch was locked in portrait mode ( my app is landscape only) . UINavigationController used a navigation bar that has a wrong height (too big like if it was in portrait). The solution I found is to add a delegate to the UINavigationController, and implement navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations to only return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape