# Safe Area Size changes after orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, orientation

I am running into a very odd, frustrating problem. When my view is initially loaded in portrait the safe area layout guides are the size expected. However, after rotating to landscape and then *back* to Portrait they are different than the initial load. This is throwing off all subviews on iPhone X.

I added print statements to `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`

```
print("View Size: \(view.frame.size)")
print("View Layout Size: \(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.size)")
```

When running the app and performing the orientation changes the output is:

Before orientation change:

```
View Size: (375.0, 812.0)
View Layout Size: (375.0, 734.0)
```

Landscape:

```
View Size: (812.0, 375.0)
View Layout Size: (724.0, 354.0)
```

Back to Portrait:

```
View Size: (375.0, 812.0)
View Layout Size: (383.0, 734.0)
```

As you can see, the view size didn't change. However, the layout guide size is **8px** wider.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933337/safearealayoutguide-returning-wrong-values-on-blocked-rotation

Comment: Is this happening only on Device? I'm not seeing it on `X` simulator... I get consistent `375`

Comment: It is happening on the Simulator and the device.

Comment: Also note, this is not happening on all my view controllers, just this particular one. What is different I don't know, and that's what is so frustrating.

Comment: Is it in a container? Such as NavController or TabBarController or ContainerView?

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to use `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor` and variations thereof instead of `layoutFrame.size` for your constraints? Is there a reason you're using `.size`?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, I am anchoring against leading/trailing, etc. I am just printing out the size for debugging. The anchors are "pulling" the subviews too wide as the size changes.

Comment: Are you maybe changing window.rootViewController? I noticed that before changing everythig works nicely but after safe area of inputAccessoryView window is messed up.

Comment: I had this problem because I didn't have leading and trailing constraints set to a top level container view, rather I was using a centerX constraint coupled with a width constraint

Comment: Happening with me also, with xcode 10 and simulator XS and XR as I have not physical device with notch display can not test on that. Any solution ?